# Complexity of arbitrary matrix multiplications

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, time-complexity

I've got a simple question concerning the implementation of matrix multiplications. I know that there are algorithms for matrices of equal size (n x n) that have a complexity of O(n^2.xxx). But if I have two matrices A and B of different sizes (p x q, q x r), what would be the minimal complexity of the implementation to date? I would guess it is O(pqr) since I would implement a multiplication with 3 nested loops with p, q and r iterations. In particular, does anyone now how the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) library implements a multiplication?

Comment: Have you looked at the Eigen source code?

Comment: Yes, I did not understand it. I'm not a great mathematician. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common technique is to pad matrices with size (p*q, q*r), so that their sizes becomes (n*n).  Then, you can apply Strassen's algorithm.

Comment: Are there any publications about this or are there any libraries that use this technique?

Comment: Hmm.  Strassen's algorithm is about recursive partition into equal sizes.  So is binary search.  The way to do a fast binary search on a non-power of two is do a first step that decides which power-of-two-size remaing chunk to search, and then does efficient binary search that divides exactly by two.  I'd expect a similar concept to work for Strassen; where you don't get a neat partition, make an ugly one, do Strassen on the big binary chunk and apply strassen and fixups to what is left.  (Quad trees do something like this very successfully).

Answer (score 2):

You're correct about it being O(pqr) for exactly the reasons you stated.

I'm not sure how Eigen implements it, but there are many ways to optimize matrix multiplication algorithms, such as optimizing cache performance by [tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling) and being aware of whether the language you're using is [row major or column major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (you want the inner loops to access memory in as small steps as possible to prevent cache misses). Some other optimization techniques are detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xiangfan/archive/2009/04/28/optimize-your-code-matrix-multiplication.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As Yu-Had Lyu mentioned you can pad them with zeroes, but unless p,q and r are close the complexity degenerates (time to perform the padding).

To answer your other question about how Eigen implements it:

The way numerics packages implement matrix multiplication is normally by using the typical O(pqr) algorithm, but heavily optimised in `non-mathematical' ways: blocking for better cache locality, using special processor instructions (SIMD etc.)

Some packages (MATLAB, Octave, ublas) use two libraries called BLAS and LAPACK which provide linear algebra primitives (like matrix multiplication) heavily optimised in this way (sometimes using hardware-specific optimisations).

AFAIK, Eigen simply uses blocking and SIMD instructions.

Few common numeric libraries (Eigen included) use [Strassen Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm). The reason for this is actually very interesting: while the complexity is better (O(n^(log2 7))) the hidden constants behind the big Oh are very large due to all the additions performed - in other words the algorithm is only useful in practice for *very* large matrices.

**Note:** There is an even more efficient (in terms of asymptotic complexity) algorithm than Strassen's algorithm: the [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) with O(n^(2.3727)), but for which the constants are so large, that it is unlikely that it will ever be used in practice. It is in fact believed that there exists an algorithm that runs in O(n^2) (which is the trivial lower-bound, since any algorithm needs to at least read the n^2 elements of the matrices).